# Trying to use HTML DOM parser to get main image on Amazon page

Tags: php, html, parsing, dom

I'm trying to use HTML DOM Parser to get the image source of the "main" product image no matter what product page the parser is being pointed to.

On every page it seems that that image has the id "landingImage". 
You would think that this should do the trick:

```
$finalarray[$i][2] = $html->find('img[id="landingImage"]', 0)->src;
```

But no such luck.

I also tried

```
    foreach($html->find('img') as $e)
    if (strpos($e,'landingImage') !== false) { 
        $finalarray[$i][2] = $e->src;
    }
```

I noticed that usually the image source has SY300 or SX300 so I did this:

```
    foreach($html->find('img') as $e)
    if (strpos($e,'SX300') !== false) { 
        $finalarray[$i][2] = $e->src;
    }
    else if (strpos($e,'SY300') !== false) { 
        $finalarray[$i][2] = $e->src;
    }
```

Unfortunately some image source links don't contain that, example:

```
http://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B001O21H00/ref=as_li_ss_tl?ie=UTF8&camp=1789&creative=390957&creativeASIN=B001O21H00&linkCode=as2&tag=bmref-20
```

Comment: Dagon, you need to be an amazon affiliate to use the api and they are annoying to accept websites in its beginning stages

Comment: bounty for "not enough attention." amazon link with associate `tag` in post. not a single question mark. fishy

Answer (score 4):

Using the Amazon API might be the better solution, but this is not the question.

As I downloaded the html from the sample web page (content without running JavaScript), I could not find any tag with `id="landingImage"`<sup>[1]</sup>. But I could find an image tag with `id="main-image"`. Trying to extract this tag with DOMDocument wasn't successful. Somehow the methods `loadHTML()` and `loadHTMLFile()` were't able to parse the html.

But the interesting part can be extracted with a regular expression. The following code will give you the image source:

```
$url = 'http://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B001O21H00/ref=as_li_ss_tl?ie=UTF8&camp=1789&creative=390957&creativeASIN=B001O21H00&linkCode=as2&tag=bmref-20';
$html = file_get_contents($url);

$matches = array();
if (preg_match('#<img[^>]*id="main-image"[^>]*src="(.*?)"[^>]*>#', $html, $matches)) {
    $src = $matches[1];
}

// The source of the image is
// $src: 'http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/21JzKZ9%2BYGL.jpg'
```

---

<sup>[1]</sup> The html source was downloaded within php with the function `file_get_contents`. Downloading the html source with Firefox results in a different html code. In the last case you will find an image tag with the id attribute "landingImage" (JavaScript is NOT enabled!). It seems that the downloaded html source depends on the client (headers in the http request).

Answer (score 1):

On page with your example img tag with `id="landingImage"` don't contains attribute src. This attribute is  added by JavaScript.

But this tag contains attribute `data-a-dynamic-image` with value `{"http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/21JzKZ9%2BYGL.jpg":[200,200]}`

You can try get value for this attribute and then just parse value. By regexp or by strpos and substr functions.

Comment: How will you run the JavaScript within php?

Comment: @Henrik I didn't run JavaScript in PHP. I just compare HTML soure of page and HTML in browser (within firebug)

Answer (score 1):

It looks like not every page uses the same html. You will need to check for many possibilities and log cases when images are not found so you can add support for them. For instance:

```
$url = 'http://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B001O21H00/ref=as_li_ss_tl?ie=UTF8&camp=1789&creative=390957&creativeASIN=B001O21H00&linkCode=as2&tag=bmref-20';

$html = file_get_html($url);

$image = $html->find('img[id="landingImage"]', 0);

if(!is_object($image)) {
  $image = $html->find('img[id="main-image"]', 0);
}

if(!is_object($image)) {
  // Log the error to apache error log
  error_log('Could not find amazon image: ' + $url);
} else {
  print $image->src;
}
```